# do search engines crawl the source or destination page when using 301,302 redirect?

Tags: html, http, search, seo

What search do when they found different status code?

- 302
- 301
- 404
- etc...

I knew they would ignore the pages with 404 status code but what about the other statuses

do search engines crawl the source or destination page?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From **["301 Redirects and Search Engine Optimization"](http://www.theinternetdigest.net/archive/301-redirects-seo.html)**:

> From a search engine perspective, 301
>   redirects are the **only acceptable way** 
>   to redirect URLs.  In the case of
>   moved pages, search engines will index
>   only the new URL, but will transfer
>   link popularity from the old URL to
>   the new one so that search engine
>   rankings are not affected. The same
>   behavior occurs when additional
>   domains are set to point to the main
>   domain through a 301 redirect.

**Edit:** 
Take a look at these pages describing the difference between 301 and 302 redirects, and why 302's should usually be avoided: [Here](http://www.iprospect.com/media/newsletter_may05_mccracken.htm), [Here](http://seotoday.com/seo-tips/the-rundown-on-301-and-302-redirects) and [Here](http://www.hochmanconsultants.com/articles/301-versus-302.shtml).

Comment: Does this mean search engines ignore both the source and destination page in case of 302 redirects?

Comment: It can get a little confusing when using 302 redirects. Depending on how the search engine interprets things, you may or may not end up with both pages indexed (dividing your link popularity) or neither indexed when using 302 redirects. The simplest solution is to avoid it altogether by using 301 redirects instead of 302.